# Convertir un formato fecha en otro

Tags: java, date

Estoy llamando desde mi aplicación java a un servicio Rest y me devuelve una fecha en el siguiente formato (es de tipo String, no Date):

```
Mon Oct 02 00:00:00 EST 2020
```

Y me gustaría transformarlo en el siguiente formato para compararlo con una fecha de mi BBDD (que tiene dicho formato):

```
yyyyMMdd
```

¿Hay alguna manera de hacerlo? si hay otra forma de comparar estas dos fechas soy todo oídos.

Comment: Te faltó mostrarnos cómo tienes la fecha que obtienes de la BD. Entregar otro string con ese formato es fácil, pero no es evidente que te sirva para la comparación que indicas

Comment: Es del mismo formato (yyyyMMdd). Pensé que lo había indicado, lo siento. Lo edito

Comment: La fecha yyyyMMdd está en un String? En alguna clase de java.time? en un java.util.Date?

Comment: Así es. Es un String la fecha yyyyMMdd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías intentar hacer un `parse` a esa fecha:

```
 String input = "Mon Oct 02 00:00:00 EST 2020";
    SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
    Date date = parser.parse(input);
```

Y luego darle el formato:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String formattedDate = formatter.format(date);
```

Ejemplo con ambas fechas:

[image: Mon Oct 02 00:00:00 EST 2020]
[image: Wed Mar 09 21:39:30 CET 2022]

Comment: Lo he puesto y me devuelve lo siguiente justo en la linea que declaro Date: Unparseable date: "Wed Mar 09 21:39:30 CET 2022"

Comment: Seguro? Porque yo no programo en java, pero use un editor online y me funcionó correctamente

Comment: Edite la respuesta adjuntando dos imágenes donde se ven los ejemplos, intenta guiarte con esos